# Python 2D Arrays Team Table

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to figure out how 2D arrays work and it would help if someone could explain to me how you code a table using a 2D array where there are teams 1 and 2 in one column and each player has a point value in the second column. Once I have done that I need to be able to add the scores up from team 1 and the scores up for team 2. There are 20 players all together.

Thank you!

Comment: Read up on lists.  2D arrays are usually implemented in Python using lists of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following example:

```
# Two 1D arrays
team1_scores = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
team2_scores = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]

# This is your 2D array
scores = [ team1_scores, team2_scores ]

# You can sum an array using pythons built-in sum method
for idx, score in enumerate(scores):
    print 'Team {0} score: {1}'.format(idx+1, sum(score))

# Add a blank line
print ''

# Or you can manually sum each array
# Iterate through first dimension of array (each team)
for idx, score in enumerate(scores):
    team_score = 0
    print 'Summing Team {0} scores: {1}'.format(idx+1, score)
    # Iterate through 2nd dimension of array (each team member)
    for individual_score in score:
        team_score = team_score + individual_score
    print 'Team {0} score: {1}'.format(idx+1, team_score)
```

Returns:

```
Team 1 score: 55
Team 2 score: 65

Team 1 score: 55
Team 2 score: 65
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is more info about python lists.